# How do I get data out of mysql database and show it in a UITableView

Tags: mysql, xcode, uitableview, authentication

I want to make an app where people must login, and when they are logged in that they can get their own personal data out of the MYSQL database, and display that data in to a UITableView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    @implementation FromDataBase

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        //Load Password and Username
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
        LoadUsername = [defaults objectForKey:@"TheUsername"];

        NSUserDefaults *pass = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
        LoadPassword = [pass objectForKey:@"ThePassword"];


        //Gets the php
        FindURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/FromDB/DB.php?username=%@",LoadUsername];
        // to execute php code
        URLData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:FindURL]];

        // to receive the returend value
        DataResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:URLData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        FriendsArray = [DataResult componentsSeparatedByString:@"///"];

        NSLog(@"%@", FriendsArray);

        SearchFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:FriendsArray];

    }



    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
        return 1;
    }
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return [SearchFriends count];
    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [SearchFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }


    - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        TheSellected = [SearchFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:TheSellected
                              message:@"" 
                              delegate:self 
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        return;


    }
@end
```

And Now the PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset ($_GET["username"]))
        $username = $_GET["username"];
            else{
        $username = "";
            }

//DateBase Infomation
$DB_HostName = "localhost";
$DB_Name = "Users";
$DB_User = "root";
$DB_Pass = "";
$DB_Table = Friends;

//Connecting To Database
$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass);
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con);

if(!$con)
{
        die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}


$result = mysql_query("select * from $DB_Table ");


$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($numrows!=0){


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)){
        $Friends = $row['Friends'];
                echo "$Friends///";
    }

}else{
echo "FAILED :(";   
}
?>
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: i get errors that LoadUsername, LoadPassword, FindURL, URLData, DataResult, FriendsArray and Searchfriends are undeclared and what should i put in the database ?

Comment: You want the whole login system and then data out of database?

Comment: i'll make a video to show you how to make a login system and how to get data out from the database into a tableview

Comment: I will send you a proj soon... have no time.. and can use my screen recorder

Comment: do you have the project or tutorial?

Comment: avoid using GET in your php as it's not secure, use POST instead.